# LEFT JOIN two tables with the same column name and print them with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two table in my MySQL database:

```
USERS ('id_user' - 'id_client' -> the same as the id in CLIENTS)
CLIENTS ('id_client' - 'name' etc.)
```

I want to print all the clients and the respective users. This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM clients AS c LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.id_client = u.id_client
```

It seems to be ok, but I am having trouble when I try to print the the `id_client` from the table `clients`. How can I print them using PHP? It seems they are empty... Is my query wrong?

Comment: Please show some PHP code where you try to get the `id_client`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

Either GROUP BY or DISTINCT is needed

```
    SELECT * FROM clients AS c LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.id_client = u.id_client GROUP BY c.id_client
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than that, just do the following:

```
SELECT c.*, u.name FROM clients AS c LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.id_client = u.id_client
```

This will select everything from table c, and only name from table u. The issue you are having is you are selecting id_client from both tables, which is not necessary, and causes confusion when trying to reference it with php.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c.*,u.* FROM clients c LEFT outer JOIN users u ON c.id_client = u.id_client

Answer (score 0):

Since you have field with the same name in both tables ("id_client"), you have to specify which one to be printed.

Like so:

```
SELECT u.id_client, c.id_client, ... FROM clients AS c LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.id_client = u.id_client
```